# Strange Reflection Errors

Tags: java, android, reflection, wireless, peer

I've been trying workarounds/dealing with this problem for weeks and I can't seem to get around it any longer.  I have an Android Application that needs to change the device's name before creating a Peer to Peer network.

Because the method is hidden in Android's SDK, I am using reflection.  The method I am trying to reflect is located here at line 1305:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java

Here is my code trying the reflection:

```
public class HostStagingActivity extends Activity
{
WifiP2pManager.Channel myChannel; //This channel is created and passed to system services in order for WIFI_P2P to work
WifiP2pManager myManager; //This manager is declared to get the required channel object
...
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
myManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);//passed to the myReceiver listener class
myChannel = myManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);//passed to the myReceiver listener class
...
Method method1 = null;    
try
        {
            method1 = myManager.getClass().getMethod("setDeviceName",  new Class[] {WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class });
            method1.invoke(myChannel, NETWORK_NAME, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
            {
                public void onSuccess()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DeviceName Changed Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Code for Success in changing name
                }
                public void onFailure(int reason)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DeviceName Change Returned Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Code to be done while name change Fails
                }
            });
        }
```

However, this causes runtime error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager, but got android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager$Channel
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Why is the method expecting a WifiP2pManager object when I am clearly passing it a WifiP2pManager.Channel class in my code?  Just for fun, when I pass it the arguements it expects, it claims the method was expecting three arguements and I only gave it two.

Can anybody with more reflection experience help me out?

Comment: What is `myChannel`? Also I do not recommend you access hidden methods, if they're hidden it's usually for a good reason.

Comment: myChannel is a WifiP2pManager.Channel Object that was instantiated in this Activity's onCreate().  I am aware of the issues caused by reflecting hidden methods, but in this case, I cannot ask the user to change their device name from the application, and need to do it manually.

Comment: And `myManager` I suppose is `WifiP2pManager`. If so there's no reason for this exception, although I suspect you're assuming wrong things about your code. Can you post the real code here including the definition of these 2 variables?

Comment: Edited Question Code to include instantiation of relevant variables in their respective scopes.